# Why do I need to assign to the pointer to a linked list when I modify it?

Tags: c, linked-list

In this code:

```
void push(node **head, int data) {
    node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;
}
```

Why is `temp->next = *head` not enough?

Why is it necessary to set `*head` equal to `temp`? What does that accomplish, exactly?

Comment: Consider this, you created a node that should become the next head. But at the end if you omitted that assignment, what would head be pointing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `push()` takes two arguments: a pointer to a pointer to a `node` (which is a pointer to the linked list) and a value to insert into the list.

The reason why `*head = temp;` is necessary is so that the caller's linked list ends up getting modified. Without this line, the caller's linked list is not modified.

Here's a highly simplified example of why this is necessary. Let's say I have a method that modifies an int:

```
void foo(int *bar) {
    int baz;
    baz = *bar;
    baz = 42;
}
```

After I call `foo()` by passing in a pointer, nothing will happen to the variable the pointer is pointing to. When `foo()` finishes, all the stack variables (i.e. `bar` and `baz`) will go out of existence and the modification made to the value of `bar` is never saved).

Back to the example in your question. If that line never gets called, *nothing* will happen to the caller's copy (i.e. after calling the function, it will be as if the element was never added to the list) for the same reason that the caller's copy of whatever got passed into `foo()` wasn't changed.

For this reason, you often see a different method signature for the `insert()` function:

```
node *push(node *head, int data);
```

This gets called like this:

```
// assume head is a pointer to a node
head = push(head, 42);
```

The effect is the same, but since there's only a pointer to a node getting passed in, whatever `push()` does to the list's structure doesn't get applied to `head` until the assignment takes place.

Comment: Answer is fair enough, thank you for your attention , especially the last part about node *push() is clarified well.

Answer (score 1):

It resets the head to the new node allowing us to iterate over all the elements. Push is placing the new node at the beginning of the list. Head is like a starting point for a linked list using which you can get to all the elements. If the head is not set to the new node you will loose the reference to the newly inserted data leading to memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a list-based stack (guess based on the `Push` operation) then the item should be added to the beginning of the list so it can be easily popped.
This way, when the caller would try to use the stack again the head of the list would be updated with the new data item.